# joining two lists in linq with a field as an array in one list and simple string in other list in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

```
from objPt in lstTicketPrintingTrack    
join objtransDetail in lstTrans 
  on new { t1 = objPt._id, t2 = } equals new { t1 = objtransDetail._id, t2 = }
select new { name = objPt.GetValue("_id").GetIntValue() }
```

This is  my linq join. **lstTicketPrintingTrack , lstTrans** is a List of BsonDocuments.

in `lstTicketPrintingTrack`  a filed : - seq is in array seq : [2,3,5]

in `objtransDetail` a field : - transSeq = 3 (just a integer value)

I need to check whether seq : [2,3,5] contains transSeq  in join

If it contains i need that row else skip.

apart from this two lists i have some other lists also to join with the same.

how to achieve this...

Comment: Whats wrong with: `select new { name = objPt._id }`

Comment: sorry.. Thats objPt contains bsondocument { _id : "", ..... }
so that GetValue gives that _id value to that name

Comment: So your stuck on the join ... on  <here> ?

Comment: yeah in t2 condition i need to include a condition which should check transSeq is avilable in seq field in lstTicketPrintingTrack..
There i m stuck..

Comment: Is the `seq array` a member of `objPt` or is lstTicketPrintingTrack the `seg array`. I'm sorry not familair with BsonDocuments.

Comment: Also, does the join work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand your question clearly, but I think you mean something like this:

```
var result = from objPt in lstTicketPrintingTrack    
             join objtransDetail in lstTrans 
             on new { t1 = objPt._id, t2 = } equals new { t1 = objtransDetail._id, t2 = }

             where objPt.Seg.Contains(objtransDetail.transSeq)
             select new { name = objPt.GetValue("_id").GetIntValue() };
```

Comment: yeah the where condition can be possible in join coz i need to join to join some more lists after this join.
If we put in where clause then it will in last.Is it effecient ? or any idea for these

Comment: The soner you eliminate iterations, the better. Because linq is executed top-down.

Comment: Did it bring you closer to the solution?

Comment: yeah its fine.. can u give a way to include dat condition in join itself. Because i need to join three more lists after dat oly this where will come so

Comment: You can join after the where again.  from ... in ... join ... where ... join ... where ... select ... It isn't like a SQL query, with the default format like select/from/where/order by

Comment: yeah its fine.. I am new to .net and Linq.. got it. Thanks. :)